# What math is involved in Sega's Super Scaler technology?

Tags: self-learning

Back in the heyday of arcades Sega had released a series of games that used "Super Scaler" technology, games like Outrun and Space Harrier. Basically they would draw lots of 2D sprites and scale them to produce a pseudo-3D effect.

Sega Outrunners clip for demonstration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSFjV8C5lgU

I'm interested in recreating this effect in software, but I'm no mathematician and am a bit lost on the areas of Math I'd need to study up on in order to implement a software super scaler. The extent of my math background is high school math, so I assume I've a ways to go.

Any suggestions on what topics to start with or recommendation of resources would be appreciated.

Comment: "When you look outside your window in a car, the further away something is the slower it seems to move." is the effect you are trying to recreate?